# How can I extract this type of data form state || this.state.users.filter is not a function

Tags: android, react-native

```
state= {
    users:[]
}

componentDidMount() {

    axios
        .get("http://192.168.0.101/COVID-19-SURVEY-APP/select.php")
        .then(res=>{
           this.setState({users:res.data})
           console.log(res.data.name)
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Api call error")
        alert(error.message);
    });


}
```

> axios store data successfully in the state this formate.

```
 **covid-19-survey-app[{"name":"Abdul Kader","phone":"18380183821","region":"Rajshahi","city":"Bogra","area":"bogra","address":"Dhunat","score":"4"},{"name":"Tusher","phone":"18380183821","region":"Dhaka","city":"Mirpur","area":"Mirpur-1","address":"Rupnagar","score":"2"}]**
```

***Now i want to extract data & count score where score>=1  like this format  ***

I was try like this

```
 countYellow() {
    let countYellow = 0;
    this.state.users
        .filter((score) => score.score >=1)
        .map(function (score, i) {
            countYellow += 1;
        });
    return countYellow;
}
```

but it didn't work.It says this.state.users.filter is not a function

please help me out.

thank you

Comment: console this.state after this.setState({users:res.data}) for better insight.

Comment: I tried . after console covid-19-survey-app[{"name":"Abdul Kader","phone":"18380183821","region":"Rajshahi","city":"Bogra","area":"bogra","address":"Dhunat","score":"4"},{"name":"Tusher","phone":"18380183821","region":"Dhaka","city":"Mirpur","area":"Mirpur-1","address":"Rupnagar","score":"2"}]

Comment: where is this console.log in your code? are you talking about this console.log(res.data.name)?  I meant log after that line.
this.setState({users:res.data})  console.log(this.state)